# Native debug on Android

Tags: android, debugging, sdk, android-ndk, gdb

It has been a few years since I last needed to debug any native applications on Android. After poking around a bit I found [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb) Google reference referring to `gdbserver` and `gdbclient.py`.

I found the former in the NDK

```
$NDK/prebuilt/android-arm[64]/gdbserver/gdbserver
```

And the latter in the SDK

```
$SDK/development/scripts/gdbclient.py
```

When I went to run the python script I am met with:

```
$ python gdbclient.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gdbclient.py", line 27, in <module>
    import gdbrunner
ImportError: No module named gdbrunner
```

For the life of me I cannot find any information on what `gdbrunner` is. Nor have I found any other reference to it in the [S/N]DKs.

Any idea? Is there another method to debug native components of Android not reliant upon this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear I overlooked it in the NDK. I must have been using an older version. The `gdbrunner` package is located at

```
$NDK/python-packages/gdbrunner
```

Along with other useful things.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

1.in app/build.gradle:

at dependencies label:

```
releaseCompile project(path: ':youModuleName', configuration: 'release')
debugCompile project(path: ':youModuleName', configuration: 'debug')
```

2.in youModule/build.gradle:

at android label:

> publishNonDefault true

demo:

[https://github.com/sunalong/JNIDemo](http://demo:%20%20https://github.com/sunalong/JNIDemo)